# php date function showing wrong time

Tags: php, timezone

I've faced a really funny problem. my server timezone is set to **America/New_York** (as indicated in `phpinfo()` and return value of `date_default_timezone_get()`) and now it is 23:30 PM in New York but when use `echo date(h:i)` it shows me 7:30 AM , with 8 hours offset!

My server system time also shows 7:30 AM and default timezone is not set in php.ini

Thanks for your help

Comment: What happens when you do `date` in a terminal?  Is it possible you changed the timezone, but didn't update the server's actual time?

Comment: @TheSmose: I said it also shows 7:30 AM , what do you mean of second question? I've never modified my server time and timezone

Comment: What timezone does your computer think it's in, and what timezone is it actually in?

Comment: @ali - If when you do `date` in command-line, you get 7:30, then you need to update your server's time.  Something like `sudo date 11252350`

Comment: @WaleedKhan: well my server is located in Canada and the timezone of New York and Canada is equal I think , So the timezone normally should be set to there , but the displaying time in both server terminal and PHP script is different. (8 hours offset)

Comment: @ali If your server thinks it's in the New York time zone and gives 7:30 AM, then why shouldn't PHP?

Comment: @WaleedKhan: well it's reasonable for PHP to show the same time as the server . but how about the showing timezone? anyway one of them are wrong. I want to know why this happens and how to synchronize them

Comment: @ali Set the correct server time.

Comment: @ali my server time zone is also `America/New_York`... but I configure my time zone... now `date()` return me the time in my local time zone... what is your [time zone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)...?? my one is `Asia/Dhaka`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds simple.

Based on the comments to your question, fix the time on the server and PHP will report the correct time.

If your server is set in America/New_York timezone and PHP is also set to America/New_York, that is, if the server offset matches PHP's offset, PHP will just output the server's time.

It's possible you were assuming that PHP's date() function is getting the current time from a time server or something; This is not the case.

#### Bonus

After writing the last part of my answer, I felt like figuring out how get time from an NTP time server, e.g., `time.apple.com`

```
<?php 

function ntp_time($host) {

  // Create a socket and connect to NTP server
  $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
  socket_connect($socket, $host, 123);

  // Send request
  $msg = "\010" . str_repeat("\0", 47);
  socket_send($socket, $msg, strlen($msg), 0);

  // Receive response and close socket
  socket_recv($socket, $recv, 48, MSG_WAITALL);
  socket_close($socket);

  // Interpret response
  $data = unpack('N12', $recv);
  $timestamp = sprintf('%u', $data[9]);

  // NTP is number of seconds since 0000 UT on 1 January 1900
  // Unix time is seconds since 0000 UT on 1 January 1970
  $timestamp -= 2208988800; 

  return $timestamp;
}

// Get America/New_York time from time.apple.com
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ntp_time('time.apple.com'));
//=> 2012-11-25 23:59:02
```

Comment: OK , my server OS is centOS . would you tell me how to do that?

Comment: +1 Yep, this is a common issue during server configuration. [Check out this little guide on how to set/sync the time on CentOS.](http://www.fir3net.com/Redhat-/-Fedora/how-to-set-the-time-date-and-timezone-in-centos.html)

Answer (score 0):

I myself found this article http://abdussamad.com/archives/343-CentOS-Linux:-Setting-timezone-and-synchronizing-time-with-NTP-.html really usefull in my case and worked fine for me.

As other friends mentioned , the server time should be corrected and synchronized with the server timezone.